# Richfaces tree issue - cannot be cast to javax.swing.tree.TreeNode

Tags: jsf, tomcat, richfaces

I'm using Richfaces 3, Facelets (a pre-JSF 2 version), and Tomcat.  I am working on adding a Richfaces Tree to my page, but get this error:

> org.richfaces.model.TreeNodeImpl cannot be cast to javax.swing.tree.TreeNode

Here is the code I'm using to build the list of nodes:

```
 int i = 0;
 TreeNodeImpl<String> rootNode = new TreeNodeImpl<String>();
 for( Recommendation recommendation : m_recommendationsBean.getRecommendations() )
 {
    final TreeNodeImpl<String> childNode = new TreeNodeImpl<String>();
    childNode.setData( recommendation.getEventDescription() );
    rootNode.addChild( i, childNode );
    i++;
 }
 m_treeNodes.add( rootNode );
```

And then:

```
   @NotNull
   public List<TreeNodeImpl<String>> getTreeNodes ()
   {
      return m_treeNodes;
   }
```

And my page just has this:

```
<rich:tree value="#{DmsRecommendationsPage.treeNodes}" var="recommendation">
   <rich:treeNode>
      #{recommendation}
   </rich:treeNode>
</rich:tree>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your imports. RichFaces' own `org.richfaces.model.TreeNode` interface should be used in the property declaration. You've likely picked the first option of the IDE autosuggestion to import the Swing one instead of the RichFaces one while declaring the `TreeNode`.

Replace

```
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;
```

by

```
import org.richfaces.model.TreeNode;
```

Answer (score 3):

For other readers:

The javax.swing.tree.TreeNode is used in the Richfaces showcase here:
http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=tree&skin=blueSky

It seems both are possible. The [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Trees.html#sect-Component_Reference-Trees-richtree) states:

> The data model must be either an org.richfaces.model.TreeNode
>   interface, an org.richfaces.model.TreeDataModel interface, or a
>   javax.swing.tree.TreeNode interface.

```
package org.richfaces.demo.tree.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;

import com.google.common.collect.Iterators;

public class Country extends NamedNode implements TreeNode {
```